# Which comparison operator is called when using intersect between two Lists

Tags: scala

I have a case class (`Expression`) which overriding `equals`.
So when using `List[Expression] intersect List[Expression]`,
is `equals` used as the comparator or other comparator like `==` or `===` get used?

My question also applies to `List[Expression] contains someVale`.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to see what happens? Did the result was not what you expected? Can you create a [**MCVE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem?

Comment: In 2.13 [Seq.intersect](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/Seq.scala#L873-L891) appears to work by [counting occurrences](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/Seq.scala#L926-L930) with a hash map so you may need a suitable [hashcode](https://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html) as well.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs for [`List.contains`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#contains[A1>:A](elem:A1):Boolean):

> true if this sequence has an element that is equal (as determined by ==) to elem, false otherwise.

The docs for `intersect` are not as precise, but we can reasonably assume that it also uses `==`.